# Handle database error in CodeIgniter [Error Number: 1062]

Tags: database, codeigniter

I'm getting the following error while executing database query:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1062
>
> Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
>
> UPDATE `tbl_galeri` SET `id_galeri` = '1', `galeri_kat_id` = '1', `nama` = 'Elyza Okiliyandass', `foto` = 0, `deskripsi` = 'Elyza Okiliyanda'
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\indonesiausher\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Controller:

```
        $pilih['id_galeri'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $dt_galeri = $this->app_model->getSelectedData("tbl_galeri",$pilih);
        foreach($dt_galeri->result() as $db)
        {
            $bc['id_galeri'] = $db->id_galeri;
            $bc['galeri_kat_id'] = $db->galeri_kat_id;
            $bc['nama'] = $db->nama;
            $bc['foto'] = $db->foto;
            $bc['deskripsi'] = $db->deskripsi;
            $bc['stts'] = "edit";
        }

        $this->load->view('backend/gallery/bg_input_usher',$bc);
    }
```

Model:

`public function getSelectedData($table,$data)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($table, $data);
    }`

How to handle this error?
Thanks..

Comment: Does your table have an `id` column?

Comment: Yap, i have table: 'tbl_galeri' with id: 'id_galeri' set to primary & auto increment.

Comment: Are you sure it's set to auto increment?

Comment: Absolutely sure. So, how? :)

Comment: Why is the error returning an update query but you're showing us code for what should be a select query. Please give us the model function for getSelectedData.

Comment: Opps sorry, edited. Thanks..

Comment: Hi @firewalls, if any of below answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once try by removing the `id_galeri` like below in `UPDATE` Query

```
UPDATE tbl_galeri SET galeri_kat_id = '1', nama = 'Elyza Okiliyandass', foto = 0, deskripsi = 'Elyza Okiliyanda' WHERE id_galeri = '1'
```

**EDIT**

May be you don't need to update the `PRIMARY` & `AUTO INCREMENT` Key. So remove `id_galeri`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your SQL statement is complete. You should have something like the following:

UPDATE table SET field = '$value' WHERE id = '$id'

Answer (score 0):

you can check out your primary key field auto increment field.
if in your table any data stored then first up all take data backup then remove data and ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `your primary key field` `your primary key field` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;